# How to bind or pass req parameter to Passport.js JWT Strategy?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I want to store information in the database when user is authenticated. The information is coming form the client in the request. The following code throws error, saying `req` is not defined.

Controller:

```
exports.verifySession = async function(req, res, next) {
  let responses = [];
  passport.authenticate('jwt', async (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      email.sendError(res, error);
    } else if (result === false) {
      responses.push(new CustomResponse(1).get());
      return res.status(422).json({ data: { errors: responses } });
    }
    if (result.SessionToken) {
      return res.status(200).json('valid');
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json();
    }
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

And passport.js:

```
passport.use(
  new JWTstrategy(
    {
      // We expect the user to send the token as a query paramater with the name 'token'
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      // Secret we used to sign our JWT
      secretOrKey: config.jwtkey
    },
    async (token, done) => {
      console.log(req.body);
      try {
        const user = new User();
        user.UserID = token.user.UserID;
        user.SessionToken = token.user.SessionToken;
        user.SessionDate = token.user.SessionDate;
        user.ProviderID = token.user.ProviderID;
        // Verify session token
        await user.verifySessionToken(user, async (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            return done(error);
          } else if (result.returnValue === 0) {
            return done(null, token.user);
          } else if (result.returnValue !== 0) {
            return done(null, result);
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: Is the error  coming in `passport.js` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `passReqToCallback` feature of `passport` to pass your request body to passport.

From passport.js official docs :

> The JWT authentication strategy is constructed as follows:
>
> **new JwtStrategy(options, verify)**
>
> `options` is an object literal
>   containing options to control how the token is extracted from the
>   request or verified.
>
> ...
>   ...
>
> **passReqToCallback**: If true the request will be passed to the verify
>   callback. i.e. verify(request, jwt_payload, done_callback).

You can try this:

```
passport.use(new JWTstrategy({
    // We expect the user to send the token as a query paramater with the name 'token'
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),

    // Secret we used to sign our JWT
    secretOrKey: config.jwtkey,

    //this will help you to pass request body to passport
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async (req, token,done) => {

    //req becomes the first parameter
    // now you can access req.body here
})
```

Note: `req` becomes the first parameter of callback function instead of `token`, when you use `passReqToCallback`